# Angular RxJs: Poll HTTP request until timeout or positive response from server

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I am new to RxJs. I need to poll a http request and continue polling until I get a positive response or a specified amount of time has elapsed (don't want to poll forever).

I am using Angular 8 and Typescript. Here is my code:

```
this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8060/api/portal/v1/payment/fetch/' + shopId + '/0/10').pipe(
          repeatWhen(obs => obs.pipe(delay(5000))),
          filter((data: ResponseModel<any>) => {
            console.log('Data:' + data);
            return data.status === 'success';
          }),
          take(1)
        ).subscribe(result => {
          console.log('Result: ' + result);
        });
```

The code above works for **positive response** from server but if there is no positive response it polls forever which is not the desired effect. How do I add a timeout in the above functionality?

Comment: Just add a [timeout](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/timeout) at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the suggestion in the first comment, I tweaked a few things and ended up with the following that works

```
// Create an Observable that emits every 5 seconds
interval(5000).pipe(

          // Since the httpClient returns an Observable, wrap it with a switchMap
          switchMap(() => this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8060/api/portal/v1/payment/fetch/' + shopId + '/0/10')),

          // Filter only the successful http responses
          filter((data: ResponseModel<any>) => {
            console.log('Data:' + JSON.stringify(data));
            return data.status === 'success';
          }),

          // Emit only the first value emitted by the source
          take(1),

          // Time out after 30 seconds
          timeout(30000),
        ).subscribe((result: ResponseModel<any>) => {

          console.log('Result: ' + JSON.stringify(result));

        }, error => {
          console.log('Error: ' + error);
        });
```

Comment: Will this poll automatically end if data.status === 'success'? How to end this poll if after getting desired result?

Comment: @PranjalSuccessena, the poll should end since we are returning once ```data.status === 'success'```